# Recommendation for Mathematical Function

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am preparing for **Mathematical Olympiads** and found myself very weak when I solve Function problems. Please someone recommend me Book which can cover all essential topics for a beginner like me and help me to solve those problems. I would like to learn from introductory to complex topics.

Comment: could you tell us what kind of function problems you want to improve in? Maybe give an example?

Comment: @The Oddbod Number An example can be:  Find all real functions $f$ from $R→R$ satisfying the relation $f(x^2 + yf(x)) = xf(x + y)$.

Comment: The website IMOmath has a few tutorials, including one on "functional equations" (which btw is the proper term for this type of problem). Link: http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=mbb%7Ctekstkut

Answer (score 2):

You may like "[Functional Equations and How to Solve Them](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387345396)" by Christopher Small.